# Post an object in Angular encode string attributes

Tags: angular, typescript, character-encoding

I have an object which is:

```
export class ActionLog {
    id: number
    actionDate: Date
    managerId: number
    manager: string 
    title: string
    description: string
}
```

I need to do a put request with in parameter this object. My problem is I need the content of description, but after the request the description is encode. Or I don't want it!

For example if I give "éàé" in description. It is all right before the put. But when I receive it in my back-end, I receive strange characters. And not at all "éàé".

```
updateActionLog(candidateId: number, actionLog: ActionLog): Promise<void> {
 console.log(actionLog.description); // print "éé"
 return this.http.put(`api/candidates/${candidateId}/action-logs`, actionLog).toPromise().then(res => {}).catch(this.handleError);}
```

I tried to encode with different type my string *description* but I obtained no result.

So to be precise I need the JSON Object but I need also the string description well formatted.

I hope someone have a good answer for this. Thanks.